# Get full path of text file or any file in c#

Tags: c#, templatetags

Respected Sir,
            my Question is that when I am Opening my txt file i.e abc.txt so I want to get full path of only running or opening file in my computer I have done this

```
Process prs=Process.GetProcessByName("notepad");
foreach(Process p in prs)
{
     p.Modules[0].FileName.ToString();
}
```

Which is giving me Notepad.exe path. I want my text file path like D:\abc.txt
so i can get this.

Thank You

Comment: You want the path of a file open in Notepad? Notepad doesn't provide any programming interface, so there's no easy way to retrieve that.

Answer (score 2):

```
string fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(strFileName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could attach **FileSystemEventHandler** and check which files are opened, or changed.

Maybe this will help

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/article.php/c6043

Answer (score 0):

For notepad, you can get the name of the file like this:

```
Process[] prs = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (Process p in prs)
{
    string title = p.MainWindowTitle;
    Console.WriteLine(title.Substring(0, title.IndexOf('-') -1));
}
```

The important part being:

```
title.Substring(0, title.IndexOf('-') -1)
```

Unfortunately this won't get you the full path.